# Visual studio wpf events

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm sure that since visual studio went free you've gotten lots of nooby questions, and I'm here to add onto that pile.

When I make a button in wpf I can't figure out how to get it to let me edit actions for button press. I know how to add events under the triggers tab however when I switch over into the MainWindoww.xaml.cs there isn't any code in it for that event. So what do I need to do in order to work with button events?

P.S I have visual studio 2013 community.

Comment: This [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code snippet that will probably help. Assuming that you have a WPF button named `btnControl` in your XAML, you can add the following click event handle to the code behind (MainWindoww.xaml.cs) module:

```
btnControl.Click+=(s,e)=> 
{
    // put your click event proc code here
};
```

Note: you do not need to modify your XAML.

Hope this will help. Regards,